# CSS block positioning at end of paragraph

Tags: html, css, dijkstra

I am trying to transcribe some of Prof. Dr. Edsger Dijkstra's EWD's, but running into a little problem. In his writing he likes to place comments such as 'End of Proof' at the end of the paragraph, right aligned when there is room, or on the next line otherwise. I would like to recreate this formatting, but seem unable to do so. I'd really prefer a solution using only CSS, but if that proves impossible, JavaScript is also allowed.

Please see http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd10xx/EWD1001.PDF on page number 0 (2nd page of PDF) the comment "End of Legenda" and page number 3 (5th page of PDF) the comment "End of Remark".

I've tried using the display: `block / float: right` combo which @starx answered with. However, as it is a float, it does not move the rest of the text down. Looking through the source document, the formatting seems ad-hoc, but it seems Dijkstra liked to keep it on the same line if possible, or move it to the next, right aligned, if not.

Searched through the different CSS specs, but I can't as yet fathom a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Neither example you provided appears to be right aligned in the source document. The first example just appears to be indented a great deal. The second example appears to be treated the same as another sentence in the paragraph.

Comment: Indeed, it seems he places the 'End of Remark' marks inline, but Legenda and Proof on separate lines. I need to withdraw my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the `:after` pseudo-element to add the caption at the end of the appropriate paragraph:

```
.remark:after {
    content: 'End of Remark';
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

Example: http://dabblet.com/gist/2406457

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you are giving class `block` to the element.

```
.block {
    display: block;
    width: 200px; /* minimum needed to be inline */
    float: right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this `(End of sth)` text must be on its own line, then make it a block (it could be already a block if it's a paragraph or an HTML5 `footer` element but then it doesn't change anything ;) ) and align text to the right with `text-align: right;`.
If text isn't exactly 100% right, then you can play with its `width` or with `padding-right`:

```
.end_of {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

EDIT: by default, an element rendered as a block is 100% wide. No float, no need to either clear next element from any float or clear block element from previous floats.

Answer (score 0):

If you float the extra content to the right, you will also need to clear the float, otherwise the extra content will conflict with the rest of the text.

So here's my solution. Tested on all major browsers.

```
.theEnd:after {
 display:block;
 content:'End of Latin';
 text-align:right;
 white-space:nowrap;
 padding-left:1em;
 float:right;
}

.theEnd + * {clear:right}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drb4S/4/).